# proving limits of sequences using cauchy criterion

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, cauchy-sequences

The question is as follows:

Let $\{s_n\}^∞_1$
be a sequence of real numbers such that $s_n > 0$ for $n > k$. Suppose
$s = lim_{n→∞}s_n$ exists and is a finite real number. Prove that $s ≥ 0$.

I have an intuition that this is probably most easily solved through contradiction. Given that for $n>k$, $s_n>0$ then by the axiom of archimedes $|s_n|>1/N$ for all $N\epsilon\mathbb{N}$ so it seems to follow that since all $s_n$ are eventually $|s_n|>1/N$ it would be impossible for the cauchy criterion to hold with an $s_n<0$ such that $|s_n-s_m|<1/n$

How does that sound? Could someone help me formalize this, or give some help for a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: must you use Cauchy criterion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you are proving that $s_n\gt 0?$

Comment: Using the caucy criterion isn't necessary, but its been the basis of the chapter I'm on. @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: No, I am proving that the limit of the sequence (s) is less than or equal to zero @AnotherJohnDoe

Comment: You mean $\ge?$ The problem is I'm not sure I see how you have used the Cauchy criterion. Perhaps contradiction might not be the best method... Have you considered using the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose on the contrary that $s<0$, then we have $N>0$ such that $n>N$, then $|s_n -s| < |s|$, $$s-|s|<s_n <s+|s|$$

$$2s<s_n <0$$
Having $$s_n < 0$$ is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't quite understand how you get from the inequality in the first line to those below it.

Comment: We have assumed that $s\lt 0$. So $|s|=-s$

Comment: Ok call me crazy... but absolute values are always positive?

Comment: absolute value is always nonnegative. since $s<0$, we have $|s|=-s$, it is like $|-1|=-(-1)=1$.  A negative sign in front of a symbol doesn't mean it is negative. Negative of a negative number is positive.

Comment: Ok so let me see if I can combine this with what I was thinking: Suppose that the limit, s, s.t. $s<0$ then it follows by the definition of a limit that $\exists$ some N s.t. $|s-s_n|<1/n$ and for some $n>N$ and given that $s_n>0$ and $s<0$ then $|s-s_n|=s_n-s<1/n$ further $-s<s_n-s<1/n$ (again since $s<0$); this imples $-s<1/n$, but since 1/n is arbitrarily small, this is a contradiction and so $s\ge0$

Comment: For definition of limit, when we pick the $\epsilon$ it is arbitrary and it is indendent of $\frac1n$, here you are picking $\epsilon = \frac1n$ which  is a function of $n$.

Comment: Is that ok? or is it a problem?

Comment: it's no longer the definition of continuity right

Answer (score 1):

If possible let $s<0$ then choose $\epsilon =\frac{|s|}{2}$ and for this $\epsilon$ we have a natural number $n_0$ such that $n≥n_0$ implies $|s_n-s|<\epsilon$ i.e. 
in particular for all $n≥max(n_0,k+1)$ we have $s_n-s≤|s_n-s|<\epsilon$ i.e. $s_n<s+\frac{|s|}{2} =s-\frac{s}{2}<0$ for all $n≥max(n_0,k+1)$, a contradiction since $s_n>0$ for $n>k$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so let me see if I can combine this with what I was thinking: Suppose that the limit, s, s.t. $s<0$ then it follows by the definition of a limit that $\exists$ some N s.t. $|s-s_n|<1/n$ and for some $n>N$ and given that $s_n>0$ and $s<0$ then $|s-s_n|=s_n-s<1/n$ further $-s<s_n-s<1/n$ (again since $s<0$); this imples $-s<1/n$, but since 1/n is arbitrarily small, this is a contradiction and so $s\ge0$

Is this right?